.net maui Tab with TabBar disappearing when navigating back
I have a Tabbar and within there is Tab that contain two shell content.
When I navigate between tab and tab bar item, everything is fine. However, if I click on a ticket on navigate to the ticket page, when I press on back and return to the main page, the calendar tab disappear.
This is my AppShell
<ShellItem Route="LoginPage">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"
                      Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
                      Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"/>
    </ShellItem>


    <TabBar Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
            Route="MainTabBar">

        <Tab Title="Intervention"
             Shell.BackgroundColor="White"
             Shell.UnselectedColor="Black"
             Shell.ForegroundColor="#85f189"
             Route="InterventionTab"
             Icon="maintenance">

            <ShellContent Title="Aujourd'hui"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:HomePage}"
                          Route="HomePage"/>

            <ShellContent Title="Calendrier"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:CalendarPage}"
                          Route="CalendarPage"/>
        </Tab>

        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:MapPage}"
                      Route="MapPage"
                      Title="Carte"
                      Icon="map"/>

         <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:ProfilePage}"
                       Route="ProfilePage"
                       Title="Profile"
                       Icon="profile"/>
    </TabBar>

When I log in, the following is tiggered
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//MainTabBar/{nameof(HomePage)}?Technician={UserName}");

When I click on a ticket within the Homepage, the following is trigerred
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"InterventionTab/{nameof(TicketPage)}?TicketID={SelectedTicket.Id}", false);

When I press back on the TicketPage and return to the Homepage, the Calendar Tab is no more present.



I cannot find the TicketPage on your AppShell.xaml, and I found the prefix is  InterventionTab  when you click on a ticket within the Homepage, so where exactly is TicketPage located? And how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

it is declared inside the AppShell.xaml.cs     'using TechCompanion.View;
namespace TechCompanion;
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
public AppShell()
{
InitializeComponent();
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TicketPage), typeof(TicketPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(TicketClosePage), typeof(TicketClosePage));
}

}
'

If I click on a ticket within the Intervention Tab, the ticket page is opened. If I move back from the ticket page to the intervention tab, the calendar tab disappear.

When I press back on the TicketPage and return to the Homepage  Do you mean the physical back button on the test device? After I clicked the hardware back button on android screen, the app is no longer visible.

The Tabbed page is the home page, when I finished login and land on the tabbed page, the calendar tab bar is present. When I press on a ticket to view it, the ticket page opens, everything works fine. When im on the ticket page and press the device back button, it returns me to the main tabbed page, but the calendar tab is no more present.

Could you please post a basic demo here so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?
